# Ember Shepherd doesn't recognize DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom, ember.js

## Description

I am using ember with [ember-shepherd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-shepherd) and have come across an annoying issue. Every time the DOM is changed during the tutorial, shepherd doesn't seem to recognize any of the changes and therefore breaks when trying to anchor to a tag that wasn't there when it originally loaded.

Does anyone know how to make shepherd reload the DOM without reloading the entire page?

## Example

*controller.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  tour: Ember.inject.service(),

  showDiv: false,

  setupTutorial: function () {
    this.set('tour.steps', [
      {
        id: '1',
        options: {
          attachTo: '#some-div top',
          text: 'Read me!',
          when: {
            hide: () => {
              this.set('showDiv', true);
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        options: {
          attachTo: '#hidden-div top',
          text: 'Shhh I am hidden.'
        }
      }
    ]);

    this.get('tour').trigger('start');
  }.on('init')
});
```

*template.hbs*

```
<div id="some-div">
  More stuff.
</div>

{{#if showDiv}}
  <div id="hidden-div">
    Blargh
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

The first tour step will show perfectly fine, but the second step will not locate the "hidden-div" anchor after it is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: I've found a __dirty__ hack to make this work. It appears that the DOM is "loaded" into shepherd when `tour.steps` is set. So if you break your tour into multiple sets of steps then load the next set after any DOM changes then it will work properly. Definitely not a fix though.

Answer (score 0):

In current version of ember-shepard addon all tour dom elements of steps should exists before start of tour `.trigger('start');`